# regex for stripping javascript on PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-replace

I want to delete all javascript found on a string with PHP, I'm trying to do it trough `preg_replace` like this: `$text = preg_replace("/<script.*<\/script>/mis", "", $text);`

But after doing this, $text is an empty string. What I'm doing wrong? Trying this regex on http://www.phpliveregex.com/ it seems to work, but using it in real life returns me nothing.

Comment: try `$text = preg_replace("/<script.*?<\/script>/mis", "", $text);`

Comment: That seems to work, thank you! Would you care in elaborate about why that extra question mark solved the problem? Regexes are one of the fetaures I don't seem to fully understand on development.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you do not just want to remove (escape) javascript but all sorts of HTML tags which prevent a vulnerability to you. You can do so using
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php
or
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Then you dont have to bother with regex altogether.

Comment: This is escaping them, I need to remove them. I'm indexing mail bodies into Amazon CloudSearch and for compression (and because I won't need to search javascript on my index, only the text of the mails) I need to remove them all. Also a lot of mails are having CDATA info on the body and is giving me a lot of troubles when parsing the XML.